# Polylogarithms: How to prove the asympotic expression $ z \le \mathrm{Li}_{s}(z) \le z(1+2z 2^{-s}), \;z<-1, \;s \gg \log_2|z|$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, asymptotics, special-functions, polylogarithm

For $|z| < 1, s > 0$ the polylogarithm has the power series
$$\mathrm{Li}_{s}(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty {z^k \over k^s} = z + {z^2 \over 2^s} + {z^3 \over 3^s} + \cdots = z\left(1+ {z \over 2^s} + {z^2 \over 3^s} + \cdots\right)  \quad(*)$$

I seek an asymptotic expression for $\mathrm{Li}_{s}(z)$ for real $z< -1$ and large real $s$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Limiting_behavior) gives the limit
$$\lim_{\mathrm{Re}(s) \rightarrow \infty} \mathrm{Li}_s(z) = z$$
It is easy to show that for $z < 0$ we have  $\mathrm{Li}_s(z) \ge z$, this follows from the integral representation (https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12.E11)

$$\mathrm{Li}_{s}(z)=\frac{z}{\Gamma\left(s\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^{x}-z}dx \ge \frac{z}{\Gamma\left(s\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^{x}}dx = z
$$
For fixed $z$ the series $(*)$ suggest the asymptotics

$$ z \le \mathrm{Li}_{s}(z) \le z(1+2z 2^{-s}), \quad z<-1, \;s \gg \log_2|z|$$

Numerical experiments with Maple confirm this conjecture, but how can it be proved? 
Or if it is wrong, what is a correct tight upper bound?

Answer (score 4):

I happen to recently have wondered the same kind of thing. Although I don't have the answer to your exact question, I do have asymptotics for the polylogarithm (I only lack some uniformity in $z$, but we probably can extract explicit bounds from the proof). The idea is to use [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) to the integral representation of the polylogarithm (plus of course Stirling's formula for the Gamma function, but this is actually the same proof).

To simplify the notations, let us set $s' = s-1$.

We want an asymptotic for the integral $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^{s'}}{e^x-z}dx$. We write it as
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x^{s'}}{e^x-z}dx = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{e^{s'\ln(x) - x}}{1-ze^{-x}}dx$$
and to force the appearance of a phase of the form $s'\phi(y)$ we make the change of variables $x = s' y$:
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x^{s'}}{e^x-z}dx = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{e^{s'\ln(s')+s'(\ln(y) - y)}}{1-ze^{-s'y}}s'dy$$
so that with $\phi(y) = \ln(y)-y$ and $u_{s,z}(y) = 1/(1-ze^{-s'y})$, we have
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x^{s'}}{e^x-z}dx = s'^{s'+1}\int_0^{+\infty} e^{s'\phi(y)}u_{s,z}(y)dy.$$

Now, for a function $\phi$ with a unique maximum at $x_0$ between $a$ and $b$, Laplace's method gives us the following asymptotics :
$$\int_a^b e^{\lambda \phi(x)}u(x)dx = e^{\lambda\phi(x_0)}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\lambda|\phi''(x_0)|}}u(x_0)(1+R(s))$$
with
$$|R(s)|< \frac Cs |u|_{L^\infty}$$
where the $L^\infty$ norm is taken in a small *complex* neighborhood of $[a,b]$.*

We apply this to our $\phi$, with its maximum at $x_0=1$, and with $\phi(x_0) = -1$, $\phi''(x_0) = -1$, and we get
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x^{s'}}{e^x-z}dx = s'^{s'+1}e^{-s'}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{s'}}\left(\frac{1}{1-ze^{-s'}} + \mathcal O(\frac1{s'})\right)$$
that is
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x^{s'}}{e^x-z}dx = \sqrt{2\pi s'}\left(\frac{s'}e\right)^{s'}\left(1 + \mathcal O(\frac1{s'})\right).$$

Combining this with Stirling's approximation (which is this formula with $z=0$), and the integral formula for the polylogarithm, we have the asymptotics
$$\text{Li}_s(z) = z\left(1+\mathcal O(\frac 1s)\right).$$

Now, regarding your conjecture that the error is at most $2z^2/2^s$, I don't exactly know, but we can get the second term of the asymptotics. For this, we study the incomplete polylogarithm (I don't know if the terminology is standard), defined by $\text{Li}_{s,N}(z) = \sum_{k> N} \frac{z^k}{k^s}$, and we have the integral formula
$$\text{Li}_{s,N}(z) = \frac{z^{N+1}}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}e^{-Nx}}{e^x-z}dx$$
and the same proof as for the (complete) polylogarithm gives us
$$\text{Li}_{s,N}(z) = \frac{z^{N+1}}{(N+1)^s}\left(1+\mathcal O(\frac1s)\right).$$

Since $\text{Li}_s(z) = z + \text{Li}_{s,1}(z)$, this proves that the second term is $z^2/2^s$.

All of this looks like something that should have been done quite a while ago in the literature, but I failed to find it (I blame my searching skills). The advantage of the proof I gave is that it works for any $z$ in the Riemann surface of the polylograithm, which was what I wanted when I started to look at this. And sorry, but I leave it to you to see what explicit bounds we can get from this proof, the mere idea of doing it is discouraging to me.

*<sub>Here I take advantage of the analycity of $u$ here to simplify the notations, but we could get something if $u$ was only $C^\infty$, for instance.</sub>